# How do I switch TFS 2012 databases from one sql server to another?

Tags: sql-server, version-control, tfs

I have to switch the sql server databases that TFS uses from one server to another. I don't use reporting services or sharepoint services. I just need to switch the collection and configuration DB. How do I do this? I went through this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620932(v=vs.110).aspx - and I managed to backup and restore the DBs, but now how do I configure the TFS application tier to use this new sql instance? The doc seems to state that I can 'upgrade' but the 'upgrade' is grayed out for me.... ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unistall TFS and then reinstall it. After the re-installation, during the configuration, you should be able to choose 'upgrade'.

Comment: But then I need to reconfigure the build service, and I was trying to avoid that...

Comment: You can also try this: go to Team Foundation Server Administration Console, click Remove Feature to remove Team Foundation Application Server. And then try Configure Installed Features and see if the Upgrade option becomes available.